# Loop of L' Hopital's Rule?

Tags: limits

Consider $\lim _{x\to 5^-}\frac{\left(-x\right)}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$ .

When we apply L' Hopital's Rule to this limit, we get $\lim _{x\to 5^-}\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x}$ and if we apply the rule again we get this $\lim _{x\to 5^-}\frac{\left(-x\right)}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$, which is what we started with.

Now I know how to solve this using f(x)=c  and c<0 and g(x)= 0 through positive values so it should be -$\infty$, but the L' Hopital Rule fails to produce a real answer on a indeterminate limit. This has happened for the first time to me. Is this correct? Can the L'Hopital Rule fail? Are their any more examples?

Comment: Once you apply L'Hopital's once, you no longer have an indeterminate form of limit for quotients. So, there's no need to (and, in fact, you can't) apply L'Hopital's again.

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x \to 5^-} \frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x}$ is very easy to calculate, no? After all, the denominator goes to a sensible non-zero value.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. But the answer should be $-\infty$ and by doing it algrebraically we get 0 as an answer. How so? @peek-a-boo

Comment: my bad. The very first limit is already not an indeterminate form for quotients as the numerator has a finite non-zero limit (namely $-5$), so you can't even start with L'Hopital's lol. You just look at it directly. The numerator is negative, while the denominator is positive and approaching zero, so the quotient goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only apply Lhopital's rule if your limit is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Your limit is of the form $5/0$; so you cannot use Lhopital's rule here. Judging by the form of the quotient,  the answer is most likely either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, you just have to determine the sign.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.